# Why is the decay $\rho ^+ \rightarrow \rho ^0 \pi^+$ allowed by parity conservation and angular momentum conservation?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, parity, strong-force

In the following decay:
$$\rho ^+ \rightarrow \rho ^0 \pi^+$$
where $\rho^+$ and $\rho^0$has $J^P = 1^-$ and $\pi^+$ has $J^P = 0^-$

The parity conservation $P$ entails that $L$ (orbital angular momentum) must be odd. The total angular momentum $J$ conservation implies that the final $J$ must be 1 and hence $L$ must be 0 (since $J_{initial} = J_{final}  = 1 + 0 + L$. So why is this decay allowed?

Comment: I don't see that mode listed: http://pdg.lbl.gov/2012/listings/rpp2012-list-rho-770.pdf

Comment: Surely that's kinematically disallowed? There isn't enough rest mass on the left to make the products.

Comment: Beyond isospin  and G-parity considerations that you summarily omitted, you may add two spin 1s to get a spin 1, quantum mechanically, no? But the energy insufficiency is unforgiving. Where are you getting this "allowed" from?

Comment: Did you check the decays of ρ(1450)? Do you understand them?

Comment: @JEB yes the decay is not energetically possible, but I was just asking if parity conservation and total angular momentum conservation were followed in this decay.

Comment: right, energy. I think of rho mesons as heavy photons.